# eloquent - query builder running raw sql with bindings

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, eloquent

I have a raw sql query code that I want to run using laravel query builder out of laravel :

```
 $q = "SELECT * FROM wp_posts WHERE post_parent = ?  ORDER BY ? ? LIMIT ?,   ?";    

  $values = ['40','post_status', "ASC" ,'1','10'];
   $q = $db->connection()->select($q,$values);
```

This query will throw an error saying that

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error
in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server
version for the right syntax to use near '? LIMIT ?, ?' at line 1 (SQL:    
SELECT * FROM wp_posts WHERE post_parent = `40` ORDER BY `post_status` ASC LIMIT 1, 10)
```

Now, when I copy the query from the error output and paste it in phpmyadmin sql runner it will run without any error .

Any Idea ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems query builder does not allow to put SQL Commands in binding variables, when I removed 'ASC' out of binding variables it worked :

```
$q = "SELECT * FROM wp_posts WHERE post_parent = ?  ORDER BY ? ASC LIMIT ?,   ?"; 
$values = [40,'post_status', 1,10];
$q = $db->connection()->select($q,$values);
```

Answer (score 0):

could be post_parent is not a string  and don't need backtics

```
 $q = "SELECT * FROM wp_posts WHERE post_parent = ?  ORDER BY ? ? LIMIT ?,   ?";    

$values = [ 40,'post_status', "ASC" ,'1','10'];
```

Comment: Yes, you are right , but this is one of the attempts I tried with no luck

Answer (score 0):

You Can write

```
  $q = "SELECT * FROM wp_posts WHERE post_parent = ?  ORDER BY ? ? LIMIT ?,   ?";

  $values = [ 40,'post_status', "ASC" , 1, 10];
```

hOPEFULLY THIS WILL SOLVE YOUR Problem

Comment: Use of undefined constant post_status - assumed 'post_status'

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it with query builder this should work.

```
$posts = DB::table('wp_posts')->where('post_parent', 40)->orderBy('post_status', 'ASC')->take(10)->get();
```

Laravel will automatically bind values with PDO.